# Issue in proxy pass from nginx to angular application

Tags: nginx

I've created an angular application that displays a page with "Hello World" on `/hello` route.

URL for angular: `http://localhost:4200/hello`

I want to make a request from the browser to Nginx on `/greet` =>  `http://localhost/greet`
And that should be redirected to `/hello` route of the angular application so that the page with "Hello World" is displayed.

But if the request is `http://localhost/hello` an err should appear

The nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location /greet {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/hello;
     }
    location /hello {
      return 404;
     }
}
```

The issue is that while redirecting, the route is not getting modified as `/hello` and since there is no `/greet` route in angular, I get a not found.

Answer (score 0):

> If the request is `http://localhost/hello` an err should appear

```
location /hello {          
  error_page 404 /error404.html; #Add this snippted
} 

# Will give you the desire error 404 page.
```

> For this http://localhost/greet => http://localhost/hello

```
location /greet {
  proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:4200/hello';
}
```

should work!

**Note:** If not then add a `request_uri` in your app server and check what you are missing there. However, there is no issue with `Nginx` config file.

Comment: That is ok..but my first priority is to proxypass localhost/greet to localhost:4200/hello it. if I entered localhost/greet it gives me page not found page that should not happen it should display angular hello page

Comment: _Edited_ my answer. Have a look at check you app server(Angular App) routes.

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
          {path: 'hello', component : HelloComponent},
          { path: 'home',  component : HomeComponent},
          { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent }
        ];

this is my route configuration what should I change here

Comment: I'm not expert on `Angular` but there is an issue with the Routes. Try by removing `{
    path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent
  }`

Comment: no we can't remove  { path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent } from route cinfig because it will throw Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'greet' as /greet is not defined in angular route